# How to Locate GPS location via Username and Locator ID

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an app, and one of its features is locating a friend. This app has registration and after successful registration, the user will be given an unique Locator ID. I want to use the username and Locator ID for tracking the location of the user.(with google map pin point location and display current coordinates).
I need this for my finals guys. Please help how to do this.
I have no codes yet, cause I don't know how to begin.

Comment: I think you are going to need to make some sort of start on this yourself, e.g. lookup the GPS API documentation.

Comment: I tried sir. But I can't really get what I want. I now have GPS coordinates and location, but I still can't track via Username and Locator ID

Comment: It would help if you could provide details as to what you have tried, and why it didn't work.